# Framework could not be found and the linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, linker-errors

I install the following pods to my app (im using swift 3.0) and just tried to open it,build and run the app and the first thing is see is with the error

ld: framework not found Crashlytics
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The pods i installed in the pod file as follow
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Digits'
end

What am i missing. link of the screenshot as follow.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the image: `Framework not found Crashlytics`. Did you add the `Crashlytics` pod to your Podfile? Here is an example:

> pod 'Crashlytics'

Then reinstall your pods by running:

> pod install

Answer (score 0):

After installing the pods, you should open the `.xcworkspace` file associated with your project in order for the pods to be properly built and integrated into your solution.